# azure virtual machine changed the public IP after a stop/start

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I had an issue on one of my virtual machines where after a stop/start it changed the public IP address
Which was been used by some IOT client devices to reach my server.

Now they not able to communicate with our server

Is any way I can revert it ?

Antonio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [check the configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal) of your VM's public IP address and ensure that the assignment is set to Static, and not Dynamic.

[image: Azure Public IP Address Configuration]

Unfortunately you will not be able to get the old IP address back, but once you set your current IP address to Static, you will be able to keep it even if you restart your VM.

Comment: Great, so I cant change my IOT devices right now and I cant revert to my old IP
really frustrating...
 Thanks @michael-hampton

Comment: @antoniogbn you can also have a DNS name associated with the Public IP as well so even if it was dynamic it’d always resolve correctly.

Comment: Absolutely use a fully qualified domain name to access your service. No device should have an IP address hard coded into it. This is one reason why.

Comment: totally agree on that @MichaelHampton, however it was used for an IOT solution and some legacy endpoints only accepts IP to addressing server and dont support DNS :(